# Simple way to remove empty sets from dict

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

There's a common problem where I need to keep track of a bunch of collections in a dictionary. Let's say I want to keep track of which items I borrowed from my friends. The `defaultdict` class is quite useful to do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
d['Peter'].add('salt')
d['Eric'].add('car')
d['Eric'].add('jacket')

# defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'Peter': {'salt'}, 'Eric': {'jacket', 'car'}})
```

This allows me to add items to the respective sets without worrying if any key is already in the set. Now if I return the salt to Peter. This means I owe him nothing and he can be removed from the dictionary. Doing this is slightly more cumbersome.

```
d['Peter'].remove('salt')
if not d['Peter']:
    del(d['Peter'])
```

I know I could put this in some function, but for readability I would like a class that removes the key automatically if the corresponding set is empty. Is there some way to do this?

##### Edit

Okay I realize a pretty major problem with this idea when trying to solve it using inheritance and changing the index function. This is that that when calling `d[index]` the value is obviously returned already before calling `.remove(something)`, which makes it impossible for the dictionary to know that it has been emptied. I'm guessing there's not really a way around using something different.

Comment: Yes, just write the same code you would otherwise put in a function and put it in a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary comprehension might be useful.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
d['Peter'].add('salt')
d['Eric'].add('car')
d['Eric'].add('jacket')

d['Peter'].remove('salt')

d2 = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if len(v) > 0}
```

The `d2` dictionary is now:

```
{'Eric': {'car', 'jacket'}}
```

Alternatively, using the fact that an empty set is considered false in Python.

```
d2 = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}
```

Defining a class to implement this logic, similar to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71519621/15261315), we can simply ignore keys/values where the value meets a criteria. A function is passed using the `ignore` parameter to define that criteria.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class default_ignore_dict(defaultdict):

    def __init__(self, factory, ignore, *args, **kwargs):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, factory, *args, **kwargs)
        self.ignore = ignore

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return defaultdict.__contains__(self, key) and not self.ignore(self[key])

    def items(self):
        return ((k, v) for k, v in defaultdict.items(self) if not self.ignore(v))

    def keys(self):
        return (k for k, _ in self.items())

    def values(self):
        return (v for _, v in self.items())
```

Testing this:

```
>>> d = default_ignore_dict(set, lambda s: not s)
>>> d['Peter'].add('salt')
>>> d['Peter'].remove('salt')
>>> d['Eric'].add('car')
>>> d['Eric'].add('jacket')
>>> 
>>> 'Peter' in d
False
>>> list(d.items())
[('Eric', {'car', 'jacket'})]
>>>
```

Comment: This method could be sufficient in certain applications. Where I want to use it, it would be equally cumbersome and very inefficient as a new dictionary has to be created very often.

Comment: Chris: FWIW, you don't have to check the length like that: `d2 = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}` would do the same thing because of how "truthiness" is determined in Python.

Comment: Agreed. I was choosing to be explicit.

Comment: IMO `if v` *is* explicit…

Comment: Edited to include both.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using a defaultdict to do what you want is that even *accessing* a key sets that key using the factory function. Consider:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)

if d["Peter"]:
    print("I owe something to Peter")

print(d)
# defaultdict(set, {'Peter': set()})
```

Also, the problem with creating a sub-class, as you've realized, the `__getitem__()` method is called *before* the set is ever emptied, so you'd have to call *another* function that checks if the set is empty and remove it.

A better idea might be to just not include keys with empty sets when you're creating the string representation.

```
class NewDefaultDict(defaultdict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return (f"NewDefaultDict({repr(self.default_factory)}, {{" +
        ", ".join(f"{repr(k)}: {repr(v)}" for k, v in self.items() if v) + 
        "})")
 
nd = NewDefaultDict(set)
nd["Peter"].add("salt")
nd["Paul"].add("pepper")
nd["Paul"].remove("pepper")

print(nd)
# NewDefaultDict(<class 'set'>, {'Peter': {'salt'}})
```

You would also need to redefine `__contains__()` to check if the value is empty, so that e.g. `"Paul" in nd` returns `False`:

```
    def __contains__(self, key):
        return defaultdict.__contains__(self, key) and self[key]
```

To make it compatible with `for ... in nd` constructs and dict-unpacking, you can redefine `__iter__()`:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        for key in defaultdict.__iter__(self):
            if self[key]: yield key
```

Then,

```
for k in nd:
    print(k)
```

gives:

```
Peter
```